# How to manage seperate docker registries for elastic beanstalk through a single Dockerrun.aws.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am currently having some problems maintaining separate docker images by tags in separate registries, since `Dockerrun.aws.json` cannot reference environment variables in version 1 for single container deployment.

I wanted to know how can I avoid managing 2 different `Dockerrun.aws.json` which is a part of the deployment artifact, if I ca introduce environment variables in `Dockerrun.aws.json` somehow or if it is possible to manage both the registries in a single files please help me out with it.

Please note that *I don't want to introduce any shell or automation script or any additional commands in the build chain*. Thanks in advance everyone and anyone who would help!

Comment: An example of what you are trying to achieve would help. Specifically, I would like to see your `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

Comment: Hi I was just trying to optimize however I think for production grade deployments multi container instances are a better choice since they supports the v2 of dockerrun.aws.json where we can have complete isolation of concerns. Thanks anyway for your time on this one.